# Java Web Socket ServerEndpoint Thread Safety

Tags: concurrency, websocket, java-ee-7

Are individual ServerEndpoints thread safe or do they belong to all clients who are interacting with them at a given time?

Or another way to ask the same question:
Are global objects in the ServerEndpoint class in danger of creating concurrency issues, [like they do in HttpServlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading?rq=1)?

[This example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websockets-with-multiple-clients-example) seems to indicate that each Endpoint is thread-safe, or he is just using Set and praying that concurrency issues don't pop up?

So, assuming that the they are thread safe, does the container (Tomcat, Glassfish, etc.) create new instances of the ServerEndpoint class each time a new connection from a distinct client is established?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, each client connection creates new `@ServerEndpoint` instance. (this seems to be the answer for the last question as well).

Static objects (or access to them) MUST be synchronized.

Linked example uses `synchronizedSet`, so it seems to be OK.

Additionally - `@OnMessage` method won't be triggered before previous `@OnMessage` processing ends, BUT it can be invoked from different thread. Meaning you will always process incoming messages sequentially.

Comment: With regard to your last sentence, it processes all incoming messages sequentially for each client? (or each instance of ServerEndpoint)

Comment: Nvm, I just found your post here: https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/is_websocket_session_really_thread

Comment: What is the purpose of having more than 1 thread in the pool if the incoming messages are processed sequentially? For example in the Tyrus source code I see 1 selector thread and 2 worker threads. Why 2?